# website SQL and file upload management CMS

Tags: php, sql, database, file-upload, content-management-system

I'm searching for a good CMS that allows a user to simple edit data (rich edit form) from an SQL database and uploading files to a hosting, the admin chooses which data is editable and which not, also where to upload the images.

The goal is to fill in the database easy and datasafe (only admin-chosen rows are editable) and get the files into the correct folder user friendly.

The frontend of my website I have completely built in PHP with everything made changeable by the database

Does anybody know a good CMS system or opensource PHP code made for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best choice for your requirement is Joomla. It has a rich set of built in functionality and also having thousands of extensions. You can go for joomla www.joomla.org

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal](https://drupal.org/) is your best choice. There are others like Joomla, PHPBB, etc.

For your info: [Wikipedia has a full article about this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems)

Comment: You should pick the answer which you found most useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of 7 years ago :)
Now I am a Wordpress professional and have made over 200 Wordpress websites.
I have also worked with Joombla and Drupal, but Wordpress is my CMS of choice now.